# Quicksort with middle element as the pivot

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, quicksort

I have been trying to implement a quicksort in Java, but I can't find a way to make it with a pivot as the middle element.

Array: `String[] arr = {"D", "C", "B", "A", "A", "Z", "g", "F", "e", "d", "c", "b"};`

Output: `A A B C D F g Z b c d e`

```
private static void quickSort(String[] arr, int start, int end) {
    if (end <= start) return;

    int pivot = partition(arr, start, end);
    quickSort(arr, start, pivot - 1);
    quickSort(arr, pivot + 1, end);
}

private static int partition(String[] arr, int start, int end) {
    String pivot = arr[start + (end - start) / 2];
    int i = start;
    int j = end;

    while (i < j)
    {
        if (arr[i].compareTo(pivot) < 0)
            ++i;
        
        else if (arr[j].compareTo(pivot) > 0)
            --j;

        else if (arr[i].equals(pivot))
            ++i;

        else if (arr[j].equals(pivot))
            --j;

        else
        {
            String temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
    }
    
    String temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = pivot;
    arr[start + (end - start) / 2] = temp;

    return i;
}
```

When I do other arrays where elements smaller than the pivot are not on the right side, it works well. As in:

Array: `String[] arr = {"D", "C", "B", "a", "A", "Z", "g", "f", "e", "d", "c", "b"};`

Output: `A B C D Z a b c d e f g`

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question's code is a mix of Hoare and Lomuto partition schemes. I changed the code to typical Hoare partition scheme that pre-increments and pre-decrements the indexes in `partition()`.

```
    private static void quickSort(String[] arr, int start, int end) {
        if (end <= start) return;
        int pivot = partition(arr, start, end);
        quickSort(arr, start, pivot);     // not pivot-1
        quickSort(arr, pivot + 1, end);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    private static int partition(String[] arr, int start, int end) {
        String pivot = arr[start + (end - start) / 2];
        int i = start-1;
        int j = end+1;
        while(true)
        {
            while (arr[++i].compareTo(pivot) < 0);
            while (arr[--j].compareTo(pivot) > 0);
            if(i >= j)
                break;
            String temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }
        return j;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = {"D", "C", "B", "a", "A", "Z", "g", "f", "e", "d", "c", "b"};
        int i;
        quickSort(arr, 0, arr.length-1);
        for(i = 1; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(arr[i-1].compareTo(arr[i]) > 0){
                break;
            }
        }
        if(i == arr.length)
            System.out.println("passed");
        else
            System.out.println("failed");
    }
```

Comment: pfff... thank you so much! You are a genius. I wasted my whole Friday trying to do that one on my own for nothing because I gave up at the end, but hopefully you helped. Now I have more things to put in my IEEE about sorting algorithms

Comment: I analized the code for a bit, and I'd like to know why we don't do pivot - 1 in `quickSort(arr, start, pivot);     // not pivot-1`?

Comment: @Sheep_Walker - with Hoare partition scheme, to avoid a check for scanning past either end of the partition, the scans stop at values equal to the pivot. This means the pivot and values equal to the pivot get swapped and can end up anywhere in the partition. The index returned by Hoare partition just separates values <= pivot and values >= pivot, and needs to be included in one of the sub-partitions on the next level of recursion.

Comment: @Sheep_Walker - If Lomuto partition scheme is used  instead, it returns an index to the pivot, so that index can be excluded from the next level of recursion, but the Lomuto partition scheme is usually a bit slower than Hoare partition scheme.